# Uploaded images to Firebase are all black. How to get rid of it?

Tags: android, image, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

The user selects the image from the camera or gallery, so now the image is in an Imageview to show the user the picture. Now the user uploads it to the server, but every picture I upload is black. Why is this happening?
This is the code:

```
mUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://lalala-14247.appspot.com");

        mImageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mImageview.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = mImageview .getDrawingCache();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baas);

        byte[] data = baas.toByteArray();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());

        UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.child("Photo").child(timeStamp).putBytes(data);

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Picture upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }

});
```

My dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Hi @Jessef, Consider using putStream() or putFile(), also to use less memory.

Comment: Hey thanks :) but where do I add this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("your_image_path"));
StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);

// Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    }
});
```

For more info please check https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Answer (score 0):

```
final int backgroundPreviousColor = view.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0xfffafafa);
final Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
view.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(backgroundPreviousColor);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(cachePreviousState);
```

this helped me